# Efficient way of determining polygon intersection with bounding box

Tags: polygon, geometry, intersection, extents, geophp

I have a set of polygons, and I need to check whether they are intersecting with a given bounding box(rectangle).  What I am doing is, I am taking every vertex of polygon and checking whether it's inside bounding box or not.

```
If yes   
return true   
else   
Now I am taking every vertex(i.e 4 vertices) of my bounding box and checking  whether it is inside polygon or not, 
using  the algorithm from http://assemblysys.com/php-point-in-polygon-algorithm/
if yes   
return true  
else
return false(box and polygon are not intersecting)
```

This way of approaching is taking too much time.  I want another algorithm which is faster than this.  I tried to search for an answer on Google but was not able to find anything.  I tried for finding code of mysql st_intersects() function on github but again I was unable to find that function code.

I know there are many algorithms but, because  I am new to this field I was unable to find algorithms,So I used the above approach.

Comment: why get php to do the hard work? use mysql - though isn't the best for spatial operations to do the analysis  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005575/php-intersect-vs-mysql-intersect

Comment: i know there are built-in functions in mysql like st_intersect(),st_contains() etc.. but i want to do this in php only. And i search for code of mysql st_intersect() function ,so that same logic i will apply in php but i din't find code,if you give me the link of st_intersect() function code, that also will be helpful.